# Calling a rest end point which is packaged as a jar in a multi module spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

Currently this is the project structure

```
+-- root 
|    +--- pom.xml //parent pom with <modules>
+-- module-web
     +--- pom.xml //web module with <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Here is the proposed project structure afterwards:

```
+-- root 
|    +--- pom.xml //parent pom with <modules>
+-- module-a
|    +--- pom.xml (what would be the packaging?)
+-- module-web
     +--- pom.xml //web module with <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Spring security code is in the module-web. I need to capture the call to localhost:8080/reset which will show a Forget Password form (html page is found in src/main/resources/template of module-web). This Forget Password form which has a submit button will now call a rest api endpoint http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/{username}/password_reset , but the catch is, the @Controller annotated class which will catch this call should be on the module-a maven project. Is this even possible? Or am i missing something basic here? My understanding with multi module maven project is usually the web app module contains all the controllers and the other modules are maybe some shared classes like a module with some models, and maybe another module that does something very specific etc.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I'm still lacking in the proper knowledge of Maven, Spring Security etc. After a couple of days of reading and trying, I sorted this one out.

Its actually simple.

The @Controller class that I wanted to use as an end point to my reset password functionality is in another module which is a dependency of the main web app. This is packaged as a jar via maven. Since, it is a dependency, it is on the same context as the main web application. Calling a rest end point which is on a jar is just pretty straightforward. It is as if the end point was created in the main web app. I was thinking that end points in the main web app are different when it is packaged in a jar (as a dependency).